# Export data as a csv attachment

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, apex

Hi all I want to export all the data from a custom object as CSV and send it as an email attachment using APEX.
Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to export data programmatically or using a desktop tool?

Comment: I want to export data programmatically through apex class

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if you want to attach the file to email or something else, so I'll just describe the simplest way to export data to a CSV file.

- Create a tabular report for your custom object.
- Add all the fields you need to see as columns.
- Run the report.
- Click "Export Details".
- For "Export File Format", select "Comma Delimited .csv".
- Click "Export".
- Save the file etc.

Comment: I want to export data programmatically through apex class and want to attach file to my custom object

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this `<apex:page controller="*your controller name*" **contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#contacts.xls**" readOnly="True">`

Here you can add other code like for example if you wanna download csv file of contacts then

```
<apex:pageBlock title='Contacts'>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value='{!account.Contacts}' var='contact'>
        <apex:column value='{!contact.Name}'/>
        <apex:column value='{!contact.MailingCity}'/>
        <apex:column value='{!contact.Phone}'/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Hope so this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to attach csv of query to a record:

```
Attachment a = new Attachment(ParentId = 'Parent_Record_Id_Here', Name='Test Attachment.csv');
Blob body = Blob.valueOf(getCsvFromSOQL());
a.Body = body;
insert a;

String getCsvFromSOQL(){
    //do query and build csv string
    csvString = '';
    //List<Something__c> things = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Something__c];
    // build your csv
    csvString = 'Name,Value\nFirst,1\nSecond,2\nThird,3';
    return csvString;
}
```

If you want to send that as an email you can do that in code or look at [visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_attachments.htm) email template